# Incremental load of full database

Tags: database-design, change-data-capture

Please anyone suggest best approach for incremental load of all the tables in a database to a data warehouse , I have already developed SSIS package to do that using CDC, but enabling CDC for 100 database with 360 table will cause any performance degrade??

Comment: Well of course there will be some impact. Any transfer will involve some work, which will involve IO and CPU. This is what CDC is for so its impact is not going to be significantly worse than any comparable design.

Comment: CDC in combination with ssis package is a better solution in this scenario ( 100 db x 400 tables ie 40000 tables)?